# how can i change the lower bound using JuMP 0.19

Tags: julia, linear-programming, clp, coin-or, coin-or-clp

I have a variable `x` where its lower bound was defined as `lb=zeros(3)`, after that I want to change for each element of `lb` to be equal element of an array like `c=[1;2;1]` what I want exactly is to make `lb[i]=c[i] for i=1:length(c)` I used to do this in previous versions in the following way:

```
function setc(c)
        for i = 1:3
            m.linconstr[i].lb = float(c[i])
        end
    end
```

Of course where `m=Model(Clpsolver())`

Comment: Would be great if you could state what is the current problem and provide [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with full error you have currently got?